# difference between typeof and constructor

Tags: javascript

I was reading document about .constructor and was surprised it has the same reason of use as typeof is there really no difference or missing something?

Example:

```
var n = new Number(3);
n.constructor === Number; // true
```

and this one :

```
typeof Number(1) === 'number';//true
```

Answer (score 1):

They are almost similar things and the difference is during its call constructor variable returns us the constructor itself where as the typeof returns the exact information we are looking for, they return information or constructor but they carry the similar thing. So its a way of doing same thing in multiple ways.